# Is there a way to backup a Liberty server deployment in Bluemix?

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud

I am deploying a packaged liberty server into Bluemix that contains my application.

I want to update my application but before I do so, I'm wondering what's the best way to backup what I have currently up and running? If my update is bad, I would like to restore the previous version of my app.

In other words, what is the best practice or recommended way to update a web application running on a Liberty server in Bluemix. Do I simply keep a backup of the zip I pushed to Bluemix and restore it if something goes wrong? Or is there management capability provided by Bluemix for backup and restore?

Comment: Are you saying you have liberty bundled with your app?

Answer (score 7):

It's understood that manual backup of the pushed zip is an acceptable strategy. Additionally, I found the Bluemix documentation [Blue-green deployments](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#manageapps/index-gentopic3.html#d2e1) to be a reasonable solution, as it's a deployment technique that utilizes continuous delivery and allows clients to rollback their app in the case of any issues.

The Cloud Foundry article [Using Blue-Green Deployment to Reduce Downtime and Risk](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html) succinctly explains the deployment steps (since Bluemix is based on Cloud Foundry, the steps are similar to the *Example: Using the cf map-route command* steps in the previously cited Bluemix documentation).

Comment: Blue-green deployments are the best approach

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Ryan's recommendation to use the blue/green approach, though the term may be unfamiliar to those new to cloud server deployments. Martin Fowler summarizes the problem it addresses in [BlueGreenDeployment](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html):

> One of the challenges with automating deployment is the cut-over
>   itself, taking software from the final stage of testing to live
>   production. You usually need to do this quickly in order to minimize
>   downtime. The blue-green deployment approach does this by ensuring you
>   have two production environments, as identical as possible. At any
>   time one of them, let's say blue for the example, is live. As you
>   prepare a new release of your software you do your final stage of
>   testing in the green environment. Once the software is working in the
>   green environment, you switch the router so that all incoming requests
>   go to the green environment - the blue one is now idle.

Solving this problem is one of the main benefits of PaaS.

That said, for historical context, it's worth noting this blue/green strategy isn't new to cloud computing. Allow me to elaborate on one of the "old" ways of handling this problem:

Let's assume I have a website hosted on a dedicated server, `myexample.com`. My public-facing server's IP address ("blue") would be represented in the DNS "@" entry or as a `CNAME` alias; another server ("green") would host the newer version of the application. To test the new application in a public-facing manner without impacting the *live* production environment, I simply update `/etc/hosts` to map the top-level domain name to the green server's IP address. For example:

```
129.42.208.183 www.myexample.com myexample.com
```

Once I flush the local DNS entries and close all browsers, all requests will be directed to the green pre-production environment. Once I've confirmed all works as expected, I update the DNS entry for the live environment (`myexample.com` in this case). Assuming the DNS has a reasonably short [TTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) value like 300 seconds, I update the `A` record value if by IP or `CNAME` record value if by alias and the change will be propagated to DNS servers in minutes. To confirm the propagation of the new DNS values, I comment out the aforementioned `/etc/hosts` change, flush the local DNS entries, then run `traceroute`. Assuming it correctly resolves locally, I perform a final double-check all is well in the rest of the world with the free online DNS checker (e.g., [whatsmydns.net](https://www.whatsmydns.net/)).

The above assumes an update to the public-facing content server (e.g., an Apache server connecting to a database or application server); the switch over from pre-production to production is more involved if the update applies to a central database or similar transactional data server. If it's not too disruptive for site visitors, I disable login and drop all active sessions, effectively rendering the site read-only. Then I go about updating the backend server in much the same manner as previously described, i.e., switching a pre-production green front end to reference a replication in the pre-production green backend, test, then when everything checks out, switch the green front end to blue and re-enable login. Voila.

The good news is that with Bluemix, the same strategy above applies, but is simplified since there's no need to fuss with DNS entries or separate servers.

Instead, you create two applications, one that is live ("blue") and one that is pre-production ("green"). Instead of changing your site's DNS entries and waiting for the update to propagate around the world, you can update your pre-production application (`cf push Green` pushes the new code to your pre-production application), test it with its own URL (`Green.ng.mybluemix.net`), and once you're confident it's production-ready, add the application to the routing table (`cf map-route Green ng.mybluemix.net -n Blue`), at which point both applications "blue" and "green" will receive incoming requests. You can then take the previous application version offline by unmapping it (`cf unmap-route Blue ng.mybluemix.net -n Blue`).

Site visitors will experience no service disruption and unlike the "old" way I outlined previously, the deployment team (a) won't have to bite their nails waiting for DNS entries to propagate around the world before knowing if something doesn't work and (b) can immediately revert to the previous known working production version if a serious problem is discovered post-deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using some sort of [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), such as Git or SVN. Bluemix is nicely integrated with [IBM DevOps Services (IDS)](https://hub.jazz.net/) which can leverage git or an external [Github](https://github.com/) repo to manage your project. When you open your app's dashboard, you should see a link in the upper right-hand corner that says "ADD GIT". That will automatically create a git repo for your project in IDS.

Using an SCM tool, you can manage versions of your code with relative ease. IDS provides you with an ability to deploy directly to Bluemix as part of your build pipeline.

After you have your code managed as above, then you can think about green/blue deployments, etc. as recommended above.